# angularjs scope variable not updating in view

Tags: angularjs

```
<ul class="inProgressProjList" ng-if= "selectBanksDetails.length > 0">
                <li  ng-repeat="selectBanksDetails in selectBanksDetails ">
```

...

if i change selectBanksDetails(like overwrite it) which is a scope variable in controller, then nothing will print in mentioned list.

Comment: your element from the array has the same name as the array. Change it to `ng-repeat="x in selectBanksDetails"` (where `x` is any other name)

Comment: hence it is not mandatory, still i tried that. but nothing happened.

Comment: then your code is not enough to replicate the issue, consider adding more details

Comment: $scope.selectBanksDetails=$scope.temp;

Comment: as the code is confidential, i can't share much

Comment: see if `$scope.selectBanksDetails = angular.copy($scope.temp);` helps. Otherwise `$scope.temp` might not be a list/array

Comment: $scope.temp[i]=$scope.selectBanksDetails[i] on if condition i am doing

Comment: $scope.selectBanksDetails = angular.copy($scope.temp); i tried this....but changes in html page is not reflected back.

Comment: what you mean your code is confidential , make a working plunker reproducing the issue come on...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2xh09epc/

Answer (score 1):

here you go i assume you want to do something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/fuxhhLep/

html

```
<div ng-app="helloApp" ng-controller="helloCtrl">
  <p>Name:
    <input type="text" placeholder="your name" ng-model="myName" ng-change=Data()>
  </p>
  <h1>Hello {{myNam}}</h1>

  <h2>{{updated_info}}</h2>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module("helloApp", []);
app.controller("helloCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.myName = 6;
  $scope.myNam = $scope.myName;
  $scope.Data = function() {
    $scope.updated_info = angular.copy($scope.myName);

  }
});
```